# How to carry 1 from remainder when summing two linkedlists?

Tags: java, linked-list

I have two linked lists declared that hold a set of numbers that represent a complete integer. For this example I am using `x = 666` and `y = 666` because in this case it needs to deal with a remainder and adding 1 to the next integer for each iteration.

The integers are automatically generated and put into a linked list in reverse order. These linked lists, however, can be any length depending on the generated integer. How do I deal with carrying and remainders when summing the two lists together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming we're storing digits in lists from least significant digit to most significant digit. In other words, the number 143 would be represented in list form as:

```
  [3] -> [4] -> [1]
   ^             ^
   |             |
 front         back
```

Storing most significant digits at the head makes adding less efficient, because extra traversals are needed to determine the length of the lists.

---

There are a couple issues to contend with in this code:

1. `while (xInter.hasNext()) { // check if there is any numbers` only checks whether `x` has numbers, which only works if the lists are the same length or `x` is longer. Instead, keep iterating while either `xIt` or `yIt` has a number, because there's still more work to be done.
2. Instead of attempting to add a new result element as soon as you realize that it's time to carry with `result.add(rem); // add remainder to result list.`, I recommend delaying adding the remainder until it's actually needed on the following iteration. It seems easier to adhere strictly to the intuition of the arithmetical approach when done by hand.

   Additionally, `llist1.set(pos++, xInter.next() + 1); // add 1 to next int.` is tricky because you've stepped an iterator forward without being able to go back. Logic gets confusing and too much state needs to be known at the next step. On any step, only remove one element from each iterator and only add one node to the result.
3. Following up on the last point, I'd also recommend removing most of the variables and branching. `pos` and `carryBool` are unneeded and make the code harder to understand.

In my rewrite, I continue adding until both iterators are empty. Any empty iterators coalesce to 0 and we can go on with the normal calculation. For each addition operation, we do two things: 1) compute the element for the current result digit and 2) pass on a remainder to the next digit if needed.

Here's a full example:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

class Main {
    public static LinkedList<Integer> add(
        LinkedList<Integer> a, LinkedList<Integer> b
    ) {
        LinkedList<Integer> result = new LinkedList<>();
        Iterator<Integer> xIt = a.iterator();
        Iterator<Integer> yIt = b.iterator();
        int rem = 0;

        while (xIt.hasNext() || yIt.hasNext()) {
            int x = xIt.hasNext() ? xIt.next() : 0;
            int y = yIt.hasNext() ? yIt.next() : 0;
            result.add((x + y + rem) % 10);
            rem = x + y + rem >= 10 ? 1 : 0;
        }

        if (rem > 0) {
            result.add(rem);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] tests = {
            {143, 675},
            {77666, 666},
            {985, 824},
            {9999, 1},
            {1, 9999},
            {667, 677},
        };

        for (int[] test : tests) {
            LinkedList<Integer> a = itol(test[0]);
            LinkedList<Integer> b = itol(test[1]);
            LinkedList<Integer> sum = add(a, b);
            int expected = test[0] + test[1];

            out.println("a   : " + a + "\n" + "b   : " + b);
            out.println("sum : " + sum);
            out.println(test[0] + " + " + test[1] + " = " + ltoi(sum));
            out.println("Correct? " + (ltoi(sum) == expected) + "\n");
        }
    }

    private static LinkedList<Integer> itol(int i) {
        LinkedList<Integer> res = new LinkedList<>();

        for (; i > 0; i /= 10) res.offer(i % 10);

        return res;
    }
    
    private static int ltoi(LinkedList<Integer> ll) {
        String digits = "";

        for (int i : ll) digits = i + digits;

        return Integer.parseInt(digits);
    }    
}
```

Output:

```
a   : [3, 4, 1]
b   : [5, 7, 6]
sum : [8, 1, 8]
143 + 675 = 818
Correct? true

a   : [6, 6, 6, 7, 7]
b   : [6, 6, 6]
sum : [2, 3, 3, 8, 7]
77666 + 666 = 78332
Correct? true

a   : [5, 8, 9]
b   : [4, 2, 8]
sum : [9, 0, 8, 1]
985 + 824 = 1809
Correct? true

a   : [9, 9, 9, 9]
b   : [1]
sum : [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
9999 + 1 = 10000
Correct? true

a   : [1]
b   : [9, 9, 9, 9]
sum : [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
1 + 9999 = 10000
Correct? true

a   : [7, 6, 6]
b   : [7, 7, 6]
sum : [4, 4, 3, 1]
667 + 677 = 1344
Correct? true
```

Comment: Thank for the feedback. However with your first point I already deal with different list sizes by adding 0's to the shorter list. So `llist1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and `llist2 = [1, 2, 3]` then `llist2 = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3]`. So before they reach the while loop they will always have the same amount of elements.

Comment: That works, but then you've mutated the input, which the caller may not expect, and done a lot of additional heavy lifting. This approach does the job without any extra work (just adding a quick conditional check).

Comment: I think I have found a small problem. If we input, say, `x = 143` and `y = 675` we get an output of `717` but expected is `818`. Or, if we input `x = 985` and `y = 824` we get an output of `710` but expected is `1809`. I can't see a pattern in these outputs.

Comment: I'm getting 818. There might be some confusion as to how the lists are ordered. I'm assuming that the least significant digit is at the head of the head of the list, so `143` would be stored as `3->4->1`. If the lists aren't stored like this, it makes adding quite a bit slower because extra iteration is needed. Having said that, you did find a bug (`< 10` should be `<= 10`). I updated my example. Thanks!

Comment: I added how my linked lists are made. Also, I don't have an example of 667 + 677. Those were just outputs of my broken loop. The inputs both were 666 with an expected output of 1332.

Comment: You are correct. I thought not including this step would make things easier but I guess not. So if `x = 512` and `y = 295` then `xList = 2->1->5` and `yList = 5->9->2` then the output will be `result = 8->0->8`

Comment: Er, do you mean `512 + 295 = 807` which is `7->0->8` as a linked list? That's the answer I'm getting.

Comment: Sorry. `2->1->5 + 5->9->2 = 8->0->7` which is `215 + 592 = 807`.

Comment: Ah, so you're storing your linked lists in reverse, with the smallest element at front?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192994/discussion-between-ggorlen-and-moms).